# Multi-step database transaction split across multiple HTTP requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, transactions, entity-framework-4.1, ninject

I have used TransactionScope in the past with desktop client applications to roll back an incomplete multi-step transaction.  That approach would seem unlikely to work in an Web application.

Can anyone suggest ways in which multiple steps, across several pages, can be ensured to roll back if the entire process is not completed?  (their browser crashes or they close the browser in mid process for example)

Certainly, i could write to a temp table of some sort, then transfer the final record to the real table in a single transaction, but that runs the risk of race conditions.  I'd like to begin a transaction, serve several pages, each page writing a piece of the transaction to the table(s), then completing the transaction with a commit, and if the transaction is not completed, then it is rolled back when the session ends.

Or am i not thinking the right way? Suggestions?

Since i'm using MVC 3, EF 4.1 and Ninject, i'm not sure how that will affect the solution, but i thought i'd include that information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no database transaction / `TransactionScope` across several pages. Even trying to do something like that is terribly wrong.

You have two options to solve the problem:

- Use `Session`

  Store your data in session and persist it to the database only if user completes all of the steps, and confirms the save. This is definitely what you need.]
- Use workflow foundation and long running transactions.

  Long running transactions are not database transactions - they are a completely custom solution where you must implement compensation (rollback of long running transactions) manually. You still have to detect somehow that your workflow should be compensated, but this is not necessary for your solution. It is for a solution where you need a "transaction" for multiple sessions.

Comment: That means you have to deal with concurrency manually.  That seems like a code smell to me.

Comment: Handling concurrency manually in web application is quite common. Database transactions should be short as possible - in most common scenarios fraction of second. What you want to do means intensive locking in database for several minutes = your application will perform terribly bad.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at setting up nservicebus or masstransit and use their saga facilies.

Comment: a service bus seems redundant given that i'm also using an IoC that does service location.

Comment: @Mystere That makes no sense. Service buses are very different from IOC. Sagas will eliminate your race conditions and allow very explicit state transitions (messages). However you can probably just get away by using a temp table.